# GCP oidc issue with Keycloak as identity provider - malformed response cannot be parsed

Tags: google-cloud-platform, keycloak, openid-connect

I'm testing GCP Identity Platform with Keycloak as identity provider. I'm using OIDC protocol. From the web app, I am redirected to keycloak login page, I log in (session is active from Keycloak side) and when I'm redirected to the web app page, I have the following error message :

```
Error 400 - Malformed response cannot be parsed from oidc.#PROVIDER_IDENTITY_NAME# for CERTIFICATE
```

I have tested from a web app running localhost but also with a web app running on the cloud.

Comment: is it safe to assume here that `#PROVIDER_IDENTITY_NAME#` is a placeholder for the actual provider name in your code?

Comment: Yes it is. This name is a custom name on GCP side : on GCP identity Platform and in my client code

Comment: @Tazmano do you have any update on this?